# Google assistant on RaspberryPi3

Tags: pi-3b+, home-automation

I need help as I am stuck doing a project. I followed the tutorial on google developers website " https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/install-hardware" and got the assistant working on the raspberrypi with 1 led. Now I want install extra leds and control them but I can't find my way around it. Will be grateful if anyone can help.

thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome @brizzi. Could you please provide details on what you have tried to do to add more LEDs to your project? Have you tinkered with the code? If so, what specific issues are you running into? When you post a question in Stack Exchange, you are more likely to get a solution if you provide specific details.

Comment: @David. Thank you and sorry for the late response. I want to on/off the LEDs with the assistant. I want to know how to create the device actions for each LED.

Comment: Do you want the LEDs to light up kind of like the Google Home Mini?

Comment: @Roxiun Yes.I have like 3 LED's connected and also written the json action file and deployed it to the device but when i send the command to turn on the second or third LED, i get segmentation fault from the google assistant.